# Attempting to setup alias for ts-node

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias

Trying to setup an alias for `ts-node` on ubuntu 17.10 by adding `alias ts='ts-node'` to `~/.bashrc` and then running `source ~/.bashrc`.

After doing the above and running `ts file.ts` I get:

```
The program 'ts' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install moreutils
```

Thoughts?

### Update

I rebooted and now it works.  Still curious to know why the `source ~/.bashrc` did not work ....

Comment: It possibly did not work because you typed the command in another window from what you ran `source` in?

Comment: Repeated the process multiple times in same window.